# Function behavior based on Head

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, core-language

I'm figuring how to implement a function behavior based on the Head of
its argument.

I mean

```
Unprotect@Head;
Head[p_[x]]:= Kind;
Protect@Head;
function[h_]:= 0;
function[p_Kind]:= 1;

Head[f[x]]
function[f[x]]
function[f]
```

the first instance of `function` should evaluate to `1` whereas the second
instance should evaluate to `0`. However, both evaluate to `0`. Notice that
`Head[f[x]]` evaluate to `Kind` as expected.

Where am I doing mistake(s)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try `function[p_ /; Head@p === Kind] := 1;`

Comment: @rasher Thank you now it works.

Comment: @kuba your solution failed though I expected it works too... strange

Comment: Yes, but pay heed to *Kuba*'s comment - in general, doing things requiring `Unprotect` on system stuff is either not required, a bad idea, or both. There *are* times when that's the only viable way, but there's usually a better/cleaner/safer way.

Comment: I didn't say it will work. This was about `Unprotecting` important things ;) I've deleted my comment because I find myself a newbie in internals so let's wait for someone competent. @Rasher's solution works but I think it's not how one may want to do this.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry,just to understand the question. What is wrong with `function[h_] := 0;
function[p_[x]] := 1;
Print[{function[f[x]], function[f]}]` ?

Comment: @Kuba Ok,forget it. Perhaps the OP will understand my question (or me his)